# C# foreach out of scope

Tags: c#, arrays

For some reason, my array `summary`, `subject` and `date` are getting `use of unassigned local variable` errors. Does anybody know whats going on?

```
    int count = 0;
    string[] summary;
    string[] subject;
    string[] date;

    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        subject[count] = item.Title.Text;
        date[count] = item.PublishDate.DateTime.ToString();

        summary[count] = item.Summary.Text;
        list.InnerHtml += "<a href=\"#\" onclick\"showArticle(" + count + ");\"><li id=\"post" + count + "\"><b>" + subject[count] + "</b><br>" +
           "<p id=\"posted-date\">Posted on: " + date[count] + "</p>" + "</li></a>";
        count++; 
    }
```

Comment: ...Because they're unassigned. What's the question?

Comment: Oh man, people are so fast to answer =)

Comment: Chill Andrew; it's a valid question.

Comment: What's obvious to you Andrew may not be obvious to others.

Comment: @user2355806, true, but it's something easily Googled. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Arran: That's never an excuse for shoving someone like that just for asking a question.

Comment: @AndreasGrech, absolutely right, I'd agree, however in this case the question could have been avoided altogether. If the error message is not easily understood, he has every right to post and ask what is it about. However, in this instance, it's really clear he could have just searched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize the arrays to a particular size, e.g.:

```
string[] summary = new string[feed.Items.Count()];
```

Alternatively, you can use a `List<String>` instead of an array if you don't know or care about the length of the arrays. A list is actually preferable in your situation, as the `Count()` extension method will unnecessarily enumerate `feed.Items` prior to your loop.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque How do you know what the type of `feed.Items` is?  We know that it has a `GetEnumerator` method, but that's all we know.

Comment: @MattBridges, still not good: `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a Count property. You could use the Count() extension method, but it would cause multiple enumerations...

Answer (score 2):

You never assign a value to the array, you only ever access the array through its indexer even though you never created it.  You could initialize them like so:

```
string[] summary = new string[feed.Items.Count];
string[] subject = new string[feed.Items.Count];
string[] date = new string[feed.Items.Count];
```

Comment: @ThomasLevesque We don't know what the type actually is; I took a guess that there would be a `Count` property and am prepared to adjust the answer should that not be the case, but only the OP could say if there is no quick way of computing the size of that variable.

Comment: you should read the answers to your other comments before posting new comments ;)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I did.  You should have read my response to your comments before posting new comments.

Answer (score 2):

They are not *initialized*. You should complete the declaration like:

```
string[] summary = new string[feed.Items.Count];
string[] subject = new string[feed.Items.Count];
string[] date = new string[feed.Items.Count];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the arrays before you can use them, like this:

```
string[] summary = new string[length];
```

However, in this case you don't know the length beforehand, because `feed.Items` is an `IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>`, so you can't get the number of items directly (you could use `.Count()`, but it would make you enumerate the collection several times, which is usually not recommended).

A better approach would be to use lists instead of arrays:

```
List<string> summary = new List<string>();

...

summary.Add(item.Summary.Text)

...
```

Comment: `feed.Items` is an `IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>`.  How do you know that?  Also, even if that's true (which is not indicated in the OP) that's no a limitation of functionality; it's an indication that there is at least some given functionality.  It may or may not be the case that there is a way to access an already computed length field; we simply can't know given the information in the question.

Comment: @Servy, I know it because it's in the documentation... http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb340171.aspx

Comment: So it's not possible for any other type in the world to have a `GetEnumerator` method that returns a `SyndicationItem`?  Sorry, but no.  It's a good guess, probably a very good guess, but still just a guess.

Comment: It's a good guess, and I would bet a lot of money on it... Strictly speaking, you're right: I don't *know* for sure what is the type of feed.Items. But at least my assumption is safe; the solution I suggest will work even if my assumption is wrong. On the other hand, using `feed.Items.Count` won't work if my assumption is right...

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have correctly identified that you need to initialize the array variables with the size of the array.  To think about why this is necessary realize that at the start of the `foreach` loop the program has no idea how much memory these arrays are going to take up.  It would be impossible to say where in memory `summary[count]` is going to point to!